# RegEx to find images with specific word in the file name in htaccess with filesmatch

Tags: .htaccess

i am trying to find a right RegEx. I want to protect all jpg images with a specific word in the file name with FilesMatch. The Word schould be "Preview", i need this and i need the same to find all images without the "Preview" in the file name.

```
    <FilesMatch "!=preview\jpg">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from development.url.com
    Allow from 85.13.139.234
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "==preview\jpg">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from development.url.com
    Allow from 85.13.139.234
    </FilesMatch>
```

Like this, one is != "Preview" and one is == "Preview" ;) And a third one to select all jpg images would be also great :)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Files directive to do the regular expression matches:

```
<Files ~ "preview">...</Files>
```

Comment: I need to find all images that has NOT the word "Preview" in the file name WITH FilesMatch! Thanks!